Valuation in the local ring of a curve
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $A = k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$. Let $M$ be the ideal of $A$ generated by $X$, $Y$, and $A_M$ be the localization of $A$ at $M$.

Is $A_M$ a discrete valuation ring? If $v$ is the corresponding valuation, what is $v(X)$ and $v(Y)$?

Take $\mathfrak m$ to be the maximal ideal of $A_M$. There is a way of defining an $\mathbb N$-valued function on $A_M$. For $f \in A_M$, let $\operatorname{ord}(f) = \max \{ d =0,1,\cdots : f \in \mathfrak m^d \}.$ (See this.)
The $k$-vector space $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ has a basis consisting of images of $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$. (See this.) So $X,Y \in \mathfrak m$, while $X,Y \not\in \mathfrak m^2$. It follows that $\operatorname{ord}(X) = \operatorname{ord}(Y)=1$. But for a valuation $v$ on $A_M$, if $v(X) = v(Y) =1$, then $v(X^3) = 3v(X) =3$, $v(Y^2) = 2v(Y)=2$. This contradicts to the fact that $Y^2 = X^3$ in $A_M$. That's why $\operatorname{ord}$ does not seem to be a valution to me.

Your proof is valid, as far as I'm aware. I'm writing this comment to add some more context.
If you graph in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the equation $Y^2 = X^3$, you will notice that the curve you find is "smooth" except at the origin. This is precisely the phenomenon at play here: a curve in affine $n$-space given by some algebraic equations $(F_1,...,F_m)$ is "smooth" (correct word is nonsingular) at a point $P=(x_1,...,x_n)$ if and only if the localization of $k[X_1,...,X_n]/(F_1,...,F_m)$ at the (complement of the) maximal ideal $(X_1-x_1,...,X_n-x_n)$ is a discrete valuation ring.
Pushing things a little further, for a noetherian local ring $A$ of dimension 1, the following are equivalent (Atiya-Macdonald, 1, Prop. 9.2 p.94):

$A$ is a DVR
$A$ is integrally closed
$A$ is a regular local ring (i.e. $\operatorname{dim}_k \mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2 = \operatorname{dim} A = 1$)
The maximal ideal of $A$ is principal.

Notice that, as expected, all these other conditions fail in your case $A = k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^3)$, with very short proofs:

$\frac{Y}{X}$ is a root of the monic polynomial $T^2-X$, but is not an element of $A_{M}$, so that ring is not integrally closed.
$\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ is a vector space of dimension 2, so $A_M$ is not regular.
$\mathfrak{m}=(X,Y)$ is not principal.

So if you have that equivalence in mind (which only works for Krull dimension 1 !!!), you can provide very short proofs that some ring are not DVRs.
